# Constraints don't work on curved arrays

Tags: modifiers, workflow, constraints

I'm trying to do some curved arrays:
I need my duplicates to rotate ONLY horizontally, following the direction of my curve (Image green). I set the twist method of the curve to "Z-Up" which prevents only one rotation axis, but it still rotates backwards and forward on the curve elevations (Image Red). If I use dupliverts, the object does not rotate at all.

I read about "dupliframe" being the solution to it, because you could use constraints to disable some rotations, but dupliframes are no longer available on blender since 2.8 because of programming incompatibilities, and constraints don't seem to work with curve+array duplicates (Image Blue).

[image]

Comment: AFAIK dupliframe is now instancing: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA73I.png...so your information in the question is not right....